# Why SymPy didn't show me the inverse matrix result in the book?

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra, sympy

According to the book I'm reading, the inverse matrix of

[image: matrix]

is

[image: inverse matrix].

Where
a = e^(π*(2/3)*j), like the complex number `j`, only that the phase of `j` is 90°, but that of `a` is 120°.

So I tried this in SymPy:

```
from sympy import *
a = symbols('a')
T = Matrix([
[1, 1, 1],
[1, a**2, a],
[1, a, a**2]
])
simplify(T.inv())
```

This is the result in IPython:

[image: IPython]

which doesn't seem like the inverse matrix in the book at all.
Why did I get this?
And how can I get the result in the book using SymPy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After your edit, it is clear that `a` is not a parameter, but rather it has a precise value, that is, `-0.5 + i*sqrt(3)/2`. If you don't tell SymPy what that value is, it will treat it as a parameter, and the inverted matrix looks like that. But if you give `a` the right value, then everything works:

```
from sympy import *

a = -0.5 + I*sqrt(3)/2

T = Matrix([
[1, 1, 1],
[1, a**2, a],
[1, a, a**2]
])

invT = Matrix([
[1, 1, 1],
[1, a, a**2],
[1, a**2, a]
])

simplify(1/3*(T*invT))
```

and this gives the identity matrix as expected.

---

This was my original answer:

You can't get the result given by your book, because it's wrong.

[Emathelp.net](http://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/linear-algebra/inverse-of-matrix-calculator/?i=%5B%5B1%2C1%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2Ca*a%2Ca%5D%2C%5B1%2Ca%2Ca*a%5D%5D&steps=on) confirms that the result found by SymPy is correct, and [symbolab.com](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-multiply-calculator/%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D1%261%261%5C%5C%20%201%26a%5E%7B2%7D%26a%5C%5C%20%201%26a%26a%5E%7B2%7D%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D1%261%261%5C%5C%201%26a%26a%5E%7B2%7D%5C%5C%201%26a%5E%7B2%7D%26a%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D) shows that the result provided by your book is wrong, because if you multiply A * A<sup>-1</sup> you don't get the identity matrix.

Comment: Sorry for didn't make it clear that a = e^(π*(2/3)*j) which might affect the result, just edited the question.